# Shell - Compare Less Than Double

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# Obtain the server load
loadavg=`uptime |cut -d , -f 4|cut -d : -f 2`
thisloadavg=`echo $loadavg|awk -F \. '{print $1}'`

if [ "$thisloadavg" -eq "0.01" ]; then

ulimit  -n 65536
service nginx restart
service php-fpm restart

fi
```

The error is:

```
./loadcheck.sh: line 7: [: 0.01: integer expression expected
```

I want to do a loadcheck shell script that can compare double instead of integer, as i want assured the load return is less than 0.01 which is 0.00 ,

If I use 0, even if the load is 0.05 , it will still execute the code.

Comment: There is problem with you load calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in zsh you can simply use:

```
if [[ "$thisloadavg" < "0.01" ]]; then
```

the  [double [[ construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html)  allows extra tests and in zsh it allows floating point tests.

Comment: Does not work, i tried change to < , it still execute when my load is 0.92

Comment: try the statment with the string "0.92" instead of "$thisloadavg". Does it still fail? I suspect there's something wrong with your load calculation.

Comment: Are you sure that's not doing a string comparison? What do you get with `if [[ "10.22" < "1.23" ]]; then echo OOpps; fi`?

Comment: That doesn't fail for me in zsh. Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Bash 4.2. By doesn't fail do you mean it doesn't print anything? Note that the OP is using Bash.

Comment: Sure, doesn't print anything. I edited my comment when I remembered which shell I was using.

Comment: OK, not it's not misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Bash can't deal with floating point values, so you'll need to use additional commands such as `awk`, `expr` or `bc` to do it for you. For example, using `bc`:

```
loadavg=$(uptime | cut -d, -f4 |cut -d: -f2)
low_load=$(echo "$loadavg < 0.01" | bc -l)
if [ $low_load -eq 1 ]; then
  # do stuff
fi
```